# difference between both the process i.e HTTP URL Re-writing and Regular Expression Extractor?

Tags: url, jmeter, blazemeter, processors

I am still having some query regarding correlation:
1. Correlation can be achieved by both Pre Processors –> HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier and Post Processors -> Regular Expression Extractor??
2. If yes, then what is the difference between both the process?
3. I have gone through many links which says that correlation can be achieved by Regular Expression Extractor, so could you please put some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what correlation type you need.

- [HTTP URL-Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier) is capable of extracting an attribute from the response **body** and automatically appending **it to the URL**, if this is your scenario - it will be easier to use it rather than Regular Expression Extractor.
- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) extracts response part which is matching the regular expression provided from response body, headers, code, etc. and stores it into a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) the variable can be used wherever you want so the Regular Expression Extractor is much more flexible.

Also depending on your response data type you may find other Post Processors easier to use, i.e. for HTML responses it may be more feasible to use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor), for XML and XHTML - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor), for JSON - [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

See [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) to learn more about handling dynamic data in JMeter tests with example.